# Pycharm: [CRITICAL] [App ] Unable to get a Window, abort

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy, ide, spyder

Im pretty new to python and the pycharm IDE in particular. I want to learn using kivy.

I try to run the following piece of code using pycharm, and get an error:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import pygame

class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\joaki\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.9.exe C:/Users/joaki/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\joaki\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-03-15_15.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\joaki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.2 (tags/v3.9.2:1a79785, Feb 19 2021, 13:44:55) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\joaki\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.9.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cgl_glew: Den angitte modulen ble ikke funnet.
  File "C:\Users\joaki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Users\joaki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Users\joaki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 982, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Users\joaki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 289, in create_window
    self.get_gl_backend_name())
  File "C:\Users\joaki\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1228, in get_gl_backend_name
    return cgl_get_backend_name(
  File "kivy\graphics\cgl.pyx", line 56, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name
  File "kivy\graphics\cgl.pyx", line 69, in kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1108, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

On the other hand, when I use the spyder IDE everything runs correctly. I would appreciate help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now... It seems that you might have a problem with SDL2 dependancy.

Have you upgraded Kivy, python or pygame?
Try a new environment (with virtualenv or venv), brand new python and kivy.
Make sure all the dependancies are installed successfully.

Back in previous versions, kivy would  create the window using Pygame (not sure this is still the case). But avoiding calling "import Kivy" and "import Pygame" might do you some good.

Import only the methods you need from them.

Comment: No, not that i know of, but it might be some bugs with python or my packages, i tryed in a venv, and then it was unable to find kivy, and when i tried to install kivy in pycharm, it was allready there. so i ended up reinstall everything maybe it gonna help.

Comment: I've actually had a similar problem when I updated the python version on my machine.
just reinstall everything. That should work. Let us know.

Comment: Yeah its working now, i had to basically reinstall everything. thanks for help guys :)